# Error in Running a jar file in Beagle bone Black

Tags: java, linux, executable-jar, beagleboneblack

I am new to linux and Beagle Bone Black.It will be really helpful for my project to move on to next level if someone helps with my question.
I have developed a xml reader in Netbeans successfully and cleaned and builded it.When I tried to run the jar file in the dist folder using linux command in Beagle bone black I got this error again and again

```
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
        at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:475)
        at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
        at Testtagreader.TestGUI.<init>(TestGUI.java:30)
        at testtagreader.Test_XML_Reader.main(Test_XML_Reader.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project is trying to connect to an X-Server, but it can't.  Are you running an X-server?  If you're sure you're not, check out headless mode:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Otherwise, if you DO need an x-server, use Xvfb to start a virtual X-server.